# Mark duplicates in range, skip empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on VBA for marking duplicates in Column J. I would like to mark duplicates with different color. However I would like also to skip empty cells. Marking duplicates is working but it is not skipping empty cells. Empty cells are getting marked with color as well.

Where might be a problem with my current code?

```
Sub MarkDuplicatesInKonserni()

    Dim cel As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim clr As Long
    Dim i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Sample Array of Columns
    Dim Col(10 To 10) As String
    Col(10) = "J"


    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(2, 10), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))


    'Iterate through Columns
    For i = 10 To 10

        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        clr = 3
        For Each cel In rng
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
                    If cel = Empty Then

                    Else

                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Col(i) & "1:" & Col(i) & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
                            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                            clr = clr + 1
                        Else
                            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        Next
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: @NareshBhople yes, there was something else getting into my mind while typing the message. I have corrected it

Comment: Perhaps they are not empty. Try using countblank on that range. I just did a test and blank cells were not coloured.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: because they are a mess and a PITA like merged cells

Comment: @SJR you were right, there are spaces inside of these cells. I have to trim everything before running above code. I am open for other options, but this is part of Scheduled task that is checking database records. After above code there is another one for deleting "not colored" cells, generating separate Workbook and sending it to email address.

Comment: @HTH - what is?

Comment: @SJR I was talking about conditional formatting

Comment: @HTH - I don't use it much myself but not sure what the objection is.

Comment: @HTH Conditional formatting works perfectly if you setup the rules correctly. It works instantly on changes and, that they have maybe issues with merged cells is not the fault of conditional formatting this is the fault of merged cells. They cause issues *everywhere* not only conditional formatting. Merged cells are evil.

Comment: I think merged cells should only ever be used for displaying final results. Whenever I had to write code for sheets that touched merged cells I made the first step unmerge them and the final step merge them back! They just make life difficult.

Comment: Conditional formatting is evil by itself and more the merged cells in that you begin with simple and little ones and then they spread all over the sheet (copy/paste) cluttering everything. I learned not to use them and I'm very fine